# windows 8 - how to stop secondary hard drives from powering down when primary is SSD

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, power

I have windows 8 running on SSD.  It keeps cycling off my secondary hard drive which is not SSD.  When I go to power plan I am unable to change HARD DISK > TURN OFF HARD DISK AFTER > SETTING MINUTES.  It is greyed out.  Even when I create my own power plan.  How can I leave hard drive on longer?

Comment: correct ... it's a standalone pc

Comment: You have tried changing this setting while logged into a full Administrator user, correct?

Comment: I am not aware of any other user.  I built and loaded the machine myself.  I didn't know there was an administrator account.  I think it's grayed out because the primary drive is SSD and should never be powered down.

Comment: Strange.  I have an SSD as my one and only drive, and this option is not grayed out for me (Win 8.1)

Comment: Do you have "Change settings that are currently unavailable" as a choice?   This will only appear for administrators.

Comment: You should still be able to.  Verify you are an Administrator.

Comment: I click on "change settings that are currently unavailable" but it's still grayed out.  how do I verify I am administrator?

Comment: ok now I see it ... "change settings that are currently unavailable" is in two different places.  I didn't see the second place.  That fixed it ... thanks :)